# I've created a procedurally animated Rorschach test but I don't know how to stop it from being cut off on the edges?

Tags: texturing, procedural

[image]

you can clearly see that the generated image is contained within the square or rather the plane that its on. Is there a way I can apply the texture to the object so that it doesn't reach the edges and isn't cut off?

edit: here is the node setup - I don't have the experience with nodes to see how unorthodox it is.
[image]

Comment: I guess this all depends on exactly how you're generating the pattern. Please [edit]your question to include the nodes you are using to procedurally generate the texture. I presume it may use a 'Greater Than' or 'Less Than' to determine the pattern (or similar) - in which case the threshold could be adjusted towards the edges to make the likelyhood of 'dark' sections to taper out near the edges, preventing them being cut off.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post, I don't know how to write out the nodes I'm using. its a fairly messy simple concoction. Musgrave with some texture mapping and generators for the animation and then going towards a diffuse & a transparent BSDF. Not using any math nodes and I'm sorry that I'm such an idiot.

Comment: If it will fit on a screen then just a screenshot should do. If it's too complicated you can share the .blend (but it's better to use screenshots if possible)

Comment: Done! Thanks! Don't feel obligated to stick around just to help me though. It's probably a rabbit hole of ignorance (p.s I added a 'greater than' math node later after your suggestion just to see if it would help and it sort of does)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key to prevent the texture from cutting off at the edges is to reduce its density towards the edges. The simplest way of achieving this is to use the Distance (Vector Math node) from the centre to adjust the output from the Musgrave texture. By using some maths functions we can change how quickly and how sharply the adjustment falls off as the point moves away from the centre.

I've replicated your nodes and added the ones highlighted to apply a factor based on the distance :

[image: nodes]

So the Distance from the origin is first passed through a Power node. The higher the power, the faster the falloff (so the sharper the edge). The multiply node allows the 'strength' to be adjusted and this is combined with the output of the Musgrave.

This produces the following result :

[image]

Comment: probably a more ssquare fallof would have its merits given the shape of the image

Comment: @joojaa True - that would be similar to achieve by using the X and Y coordinates to calculate the distance from the edge to create a gradient. For example, could use something like getting the 'absolute' of both the X and the Y coordinate and then getting the 'max' of those, which would produce a square falloff.

Answer (score 8):

(Rich Sedman's answer is perfectly good, but I'll go ahead and submit this one since it adds only three nodes and offers a nice Color Ramp control.)

By adding a spherical gradient to the texture, you can ensure that the edges' values are under the threshold of the *Greater Than* node, and setting the *Color Ramp* node to *Ease* will make the falloff a little bit smoother.
[image: 1]

Here is the resulting mask.
[image: 2]

Comment: Nice. As always, there are many ways of solving this. I did go down the Gradient Texture method originally but you need to be aware of the limitations of its range - it is limited to a range of 1. If the object coordinates are over a larger range you’d need to add a Mapping node or similar to map them back to the 0.0 to 1.0 range required by the Color Ramp. I generally prefer the maths node method for this reason (also, the Color Ramp used to be quite crude and only output 256 ‘stepped’ levels) - but yours is a good way of doing it though.

Comment: @Rich IMO, this is the neatest solution. (But I _would_ say that.. this answer squashes my nearly identical one :D) Just one difference, though..  OP says the surface is animated. (Folding paper?) So the coordinate system should be UV,  `-(0.5,0.5)` centered, `Absolute` X mirrored, and  `*2`  doubled out to 0-1 from the new origin, to put it through the color ramp?

Comment: @RobinBetts Oh yes - agreed. Definitely neater and easier to visually understand - and adjust. I read it that the pattern was animated, not the mesh - I don’t really know. Also, since the OP used a Gradient and Color Ramp to do the mirroring this fits in much better - although for me I’d have split the coordinates and used a maths Absolute as that’s how my brain works. It’s always good to have lots of different solutions :-)

Comment: @RichSedman Yeah, I usually use math solutions, but I already had this one ready when you posted yours :) Also, I didn't realize that the color ramp used to quantize its output, interesting!

Comment: @HISEROD Actually, I've just run some tests and the Color Ramp is actually still quantized - but the 'steps' are linearly interpolated (previously they were noticeably stepped). I think behind the scenes it's sampled into a 256-sized lookup table. There will be a performance overhead for it also. It's generally good enough for most use cases and a color ramp is much easier to manipulate so the benefits usually far outweigh the downsides.

Comment: hmm... I checked it out as well, but only got quantization when it was set to B-spline. I wasn't able to find the source code for B-spline on github though.